# For/If Loop has no errors but does not push the value to the array

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, remix

I am trying to create a whitelist. I've used a for and if loop to check if the msg.sender already exists in the array. When the whitelist() function is run, no errors are returned, but when I run check(), it tells me the address doesn't exist in the array, same thing with directing fetching the array.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SelfWhitelist {

    address[] public addressWhitelist;

    function whitelist() public returns(string memory) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < addressWhitelist.length; i++) {
            if(addressWhitelist[i] != msg.sender) {
                addressWhitelist.push(msg.sender);
                return "Whitelisted!";
            }
        }
        return "Already whitelisted!";
    }

    function check() public view returns (bool){
        for(uint i = 0; i < addressWhitelist.length; i++){
            if(addressWhitelist[i] == msg.sender)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I added this block of code to check for duplicate entries in the array.

```
for(uint i = 0; i < addressWhitelist.length; i++) {
            if(addressWhitelist[i] != msg.sender) {
                addressWhitelist.push(msg.sender);
                return "Whitelisted!";
            }
```

Expected for no errors and my address being pushed to the array.

The code ran without errors, but nothing was added to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `mapping` type to hold the whitelisted addresses, then you don't have to loop over the array

```js
contract SelfWhitelist {

    mapping(address => bool) public addressWhitelist;

    function whitelist() public returns(string memory) {
        if (check()) {
            return "Already whitelisted!";
        }
        addressWhitelist[msg.sender] = true;
        return "Whitelisted!";
    }

    function check() public view returns (bool) {

        return addressWhitelist[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

---

And in your code, seems you have logical issues:

```js
 for(uint i = 0; i < addressWhitelist.length; i++) {
    if(addressWhitelist[i] != msg.sender) {
        addressWhitelist.push(msg.sender);
        return "Whitelisted!";
    }
}
```

- if the array is **empty**, the loop **never** **executes**, so nothing will be added
- if the first item is not `msg.sender`, `msg.sender` will be whitelisted, even though it might be already whitelisted.

Comment: Oh, damn. Thanks, never thought of using that.

Comment: @Anim3Add1ct you can mark this as an answer, for better tracking unanswered questions on SO. Thanks